# Read daily data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to forecast electricity consumption on daily basis based on historical data for each day from 1st january 2010 to 31st december 2011 i.e. I hve a total of 365*2 = 730 past data points. I am using `ts` to read the data. I am defining it as follows:

```
ts(consumption, start=1, frequency=365)
```

Is this correct? I am mainly doubtful over the "frequency" : should it be 365? Or should I use

```
ts(consumption, start=1,frequency=1)
```

For another approach, if I want to consolidate the data on weekly basis (by summing  up every 7 observations) and then want to run forecast model, how should I read the data using `ts` ? What should be the value of `frequency`?

Comment: Can you show your sample data ?

Comment: The data looks like: 

1.763
0.463
1.113
0.475
0.688
1.238
1.263
0.375
0.65
1.538
0.263
0.525
0.85
1.838
1.225
0.663
1.075
0.963
0.375
0.538
0.913
0.55
1.325
1.138
1.1
0.575
1.575
0.388
1.025
0.55
0.238
0.575
0.525
0.338
0.413
0.463
0.263
1.113
0.7
0.575
......

and so on.

Answer (score 5):

For daily data with an annual seasonal pattern, use `frequency=365`. But if you want to model the weekly pattern, you will need `frequency=7`. If you sum every 7 observations to form weekly data, then you need `frequency=52`.

Of course, the real seasonal periods are not whole numbers, but most functions that use `ts` objects assume that the frequency is integer. You can handle these data more generally using the `msts` function from the `forecast` package. Then you could specify both weekly and annual seasonality for the daily data using

```
daily <- msts(consumption, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
```

and annual seasonality for the weekly data using

```
weekly <- msts(wconsumption, seasonal=365.25/7)
```

where `wconsumption` contains the sum from each block of 7 consecutive observations.

Forecasts can be obtained using the `tbats` function:

```
fit <- tbats(daily)
fc <- forecast(tbats)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Things are way more clear to me now and I will definitely try running the codes tomorrow. Just one thing: why is the seasonal period taken as 365.25?

Comment: Honestly I couldnt understand what 7 and 365.25 means seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25). R msts definition for "seasonal.periods" is A vector of the seasonal periods of the msts. The answer is not explained clearly.

Comment: There are 7 days in a week. There is an average of 365.25 days in a year.